# Android Studio Firebase Authentication (Fix Version of Google Services)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the API documentation for setting up user authentication. My `registerActivity` correctly sends data to the Firebase database but when I try to  set up the sign in authentication for my `loginActivity`, the login button does not go to the `mainActivity` as I expect it to. Is there something wrong with my user sign in set up or maybe there is another way I should be using intent for the login button?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private EditText emailField;
private EditText passwordField;

private Button loginButton;

private FirebaseAuth loginAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener loginAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login3);

    loginAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    final TextView RegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerLink);

    loginAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    RegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            startSignIn();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    loginAuth.addAuthStateListener(loginAuthListener);
}



private void startSignIn(){
    String email = emailField.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email Field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password Field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else{
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email Field and Password Field are Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    } else {

        loginAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Either the Password or Email Field is Incorrect. Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the log console while running the app and found that the version of google services the emulator was running on was not up to date. To fix the problem, you can either...

- Run the app on a real android device
- Make sure you're using the same version of all your dependencies (all are 9.8, all are 10.0.0, and so on)
- Be sure to click "sync project with gradle files" in your android tool list